# How to reduce the size of an exe made from a jar developed in netbeans?

Tags: jar

I developed a tool in netbeans and I wanted to make its exe file so I used Excelsior JET.

But the size of the exe goes to 17MB, even though my jar has a size in KBs only.

What should I do to make the size of exe lesser?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to bring the size down to KBs with any tool, because your program would still require the services provided by the JVM - threading, garbage collection, JNI, and so on - and, more importantly, *the Java standard library*. That is a lot of classes, and even the simplest Java program would load hundreds of them (just run "Hello, World!" using the conventional `java` launcher with `-verbose:class`).

Specifically with Excelsior JET, you may have an option to use [Compact Profiles](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/compactprofiles/compactprofiles.html), a pre-Jigsaw feature introduced in Java SE 8:

https://www.excelsiorjet.com/solutions/java-download-size

But you would need at least the Professional Edition for that.

DISCLAIMER: I work for Excelsior.

Comment: Is there any way to make installer such a way that it downloads the required files during or after installation?